# Parse only returning first file

Tags: python, python-2.7, parsing, io

I've written a function that is supposed to read each file in a directory and store a string in a list that i have parsed out. However when running it is only returning the first file. I'm not sure why it is doing this, but before I stored it as a variable and just printed it worked fine. But now when I'm saving it as a list it stops at the first file. Can anyone help?

**CODE:**

```
def ParseFiles(path):
    for filename in os.listdir(path):
        if filename.endswith(('.cfg', '.startup', '.confg')):
            file_name = os.path.join(path, filename)
            with open(file_name, "r") as in_file:
                for line in in_file:
                    match = re.search('^hostname\s(\S+)$', line)
                    if match:
                        hostname = [match.group(1)]
                        return hostname
                        #print hostname
```

Comment: Is not it because there is a match and you simply return from the function?..

Comment: So, if i understand you correclty, it's because i'm finding a match and once it does that it's exciting the loop?

Comment: Right.  You return as soon as you find the first match, in any line of any file.

Comment: Can you show the code that returned all of the matches, as implied by your posting?

Comment: FYI, you're exiting the loop; "exciting" the loop is anthropomorphic.  :-)

Comment: Sorry, Prune i guess i was "excited" about knowing it was exiting :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

alecxe is correct. You are returning from the function so it finishes executing if you have a match in the first file and it never goes back to check for other files.

It really depends on what you want to do, but I am assuming you want to collect the hostnames you find in the files.

So you can do this,

```
def ParseFiles(path):
    hostnames = []
    for filename in os.listdir(path):
        if filename.endswith(('.cfg', '.startup', '.confg')):
            file_name = os.path.join(path, filename)
            with open(file_name, "r") as in_file:
                for line in in_file:
                    match = re.search('^hostname\s(\S+)$', line)
                    if match:
                        hostname = [match.group(1)]
                        hostnames.append(hostname)
     return hostnames
```

This way, you will return a list of hostnames that matched in all files.

Comment: Ok, that makes a lot of sense. I'm new to programming. Any tips on how to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

unlike `print`, the `return` statement ends the execution of the function.

If you want to make a list out of all of the results, you should create it before the loop, add elements one by one, and then return the entire list:

```
def ParseFiles(path):
    results = []
    for filename in os.listdir(path):
        if filename.endswith(('.cfg', '.startup', '.confg')):
            file_name = os.path.join(path, filename)
            with open(file_name, "r") as in_file:
                for line in in_file:
                    match = re.search('^hostname\s(\S+)$', line)
                    if match:
                        # Add result to the list we created earlier
                        results.append(match.group(1))
    # Now return the whole list
    return results
```

A slightly more advanced solution is to create a generator:

```
def ParseFiles(path):
    for filename in os.listdir(path):
        if filename.endswith(('.cfg', '.startup', '.confg')):
            file_name = os.path.join(path, filename)
            with open(file_name, "r") as in_file:
                for line in in_file:
                    match = re.search('^hostname\s(\S+)$', line)
                    if match:
                        # Yields a single result out, but doesn't end the execution
                        yield match.group(1)
```

Now to use it:

```
for host in ParseFiles(my_path):
    # do something with 'host'
    print host
```

Also, it's usually the convention in Python to format names of functions and variables using underscores - such as parse_files()
Camel casing is reserved to class names - MyClass

Comment: YES! That's it. I was trying to append but i wasn't creating the list above the loop. Thank you so much!

Comment: I will take note of the formatting and make the appropriate changes.